# Configure external jars with HDI Jupyter Spark (Scala) notebook

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, azure-hdinsight, livy

I have an external custom jar that I would like to use with Azure HDInsight Jupyter notebooks; the Jupyter notebooks in HDI use Spark Magic and Livy.

Within the first cell of the notebook, I'm trying to use the `jars` configuration:

```
%%configure -f
{"jars": ["wasb://$container$@$account#.blob.core.windows.net/folder/my-custom-jar.jar"]}
```

But the error message I receive is:

```
Starting Spark application
The code failed because of a fatal error:
    Status 'shutting_down' not supported by session..

Some things to try:
a) Make sure Spark has enough available resources for Jupyter to create a Spark context. For instructions on how to assign resources see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=717038
b) Contact your cluster administrator to make sure the Spark magics library is configured correctly.
Current session configs: {u'jars': [u'wasb://$container$@$account#.blob.core.windows.net/folder/my-custom-jar.jar'], u'kind': 'spark'}
An error was encountered:
Status 'shutting_down' not supported by session.
```

I'm wondering if I'm just not understanding how Livy works in this case  as I was able to successfully include a spark-package (GraphFrames) on the same cluster:

```
%%configure -f
{ "conf": {"spark.jars.packages": "graphframes:graphframes:0.3.0-spark2.0-s_2.11" }}
```

Some additional references that may be handy (just in case I missed something):

- [Jupyter notebooks kernels with Apache Spark clusters in HDInsight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-apache-spark-jupyter-notebook-kernels)
- [Livy Documentation](https://github.com/cloudera/livy#request-body)
- [Submit Spark jobs remotely to an Apache Spark cluster on HDInsight using Livy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-apache-spark-livy-rest-interface)

Comment: Any movement on this?  I'm running into the same thing with `h2o` and `pysparkling`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, I was able to figure it out and forgot to update my question. This can work if you put the jar in the default storage account of your HDI cluster.

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

in case people come here for adding jars on EMR.

```
%%configure -f
{"name": "sparkTest", "conf": {"spark.jars": "s3://somebucket/artifacts/jars/spark-avro_2.11-2.4.4.jar"}}
```

contrary to the [document](https://livy.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/rest-api.html), use `jars` directly won't work.